# In my MySQL what is the difference between using the word JOIN or using: table1.id=table2.id

Tags: mysql, join, union, inner-join

In my MySQL what is the difference between using the word JOIN or using: table1.id=table2.id

```
Table 1
id  name
1   John Lennon

Table 2
id  position
1   Singer
```

//What is the difference then calling JOIN?

```
Select name, position
From Table1, Table2
Where Table1.id=Table2.id;
```

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/mysql-join-types.shtml). Should help you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none as long as there are only two tables. When there are more, you might get different JOIN order than expected, if you use comma to separate tables.

From [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html):

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

Comment: let me add another table then and see what you would have to say

Answer (score 1):

If this case, there's no difference.
But the joins can also be: INNER, OUTER (left outer, right outer, full outer joins), LEFT, RIGHT.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `JOIN` is known as an "explicit join", or an ANSI join... separating your tables with a comma and then linking them in the `WHERE` clause is known as an "implicit join".

The ANSI join is widely considered to be the preferred syntax.  It is easier to follow, less ambiguous, and more consistent when you need to start adding outer joins.

Additionally, if you use the implicit join syntax, it is easy to end up with an accidental cross join if you forget to link the tables in your `WHERE` clause.